# Updating ArcGIS Online Hosted Table

Tags: arcgis-online, table, web-service

I published a table (File Geodatabase Table) to ArcGIS Online as a hosted feature for the purposes of creating an Operations Dashboard. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to update it.

I've been able to use the geoprocessing tool [**Replace Web Layer**](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/server/replace-web-layer.htm) or the **ArcGIS Pro Tool Replace Web Layer** before for spatial datasets, but it specifies that my target layer (the hosted table) is unsupported or does not exist.

I've got a few workarounds I think could work, but I'd rather automate this process correctly by updating the hosted layer with my local data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try creating a service definition file, uploading it to ArcGIS Online and overwrite the service. With the ArcGIS API for Python, you can directly interact with items in ArcGIS Online.

**Example:**
https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/analytics/analytics/updating-your-hosted-feature-services-with-arcgis-pro-and-the-arcgis-api-for-python/

**Official Doc:**
https://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/

Answer (score 1):

Consider setting up a batch job (python script) in Windows Task Scheduler that uses the Append tool, like in this workflow: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000020494